# Question Concerning Solutions of a Congruence that is Unique Modulo m

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

I have been working through exercises in a book on polynomials. There is a section in the first chapter on some basic number theory.  I am having trouble completing one of the exercises. Part (e.) of the exercises goes like this :

"We say that the solution of a congruence $ax \equiv b ( \mod m)$ is unique modulo $m$, or
simply, unique, if the difference between any two solutions is divisible by $m$. In other words, the requirement is that $au \equiv av \equiv b (\mod m)$ implies $u \equiv v (\mod m)$. Show
that the solution of the congruence is unique if and only if $\text{gcd}(a,m) = 1$."

Here a solution to the congruence is some $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $ax \equiv b(\mod m)$ is true.
I suspect $u$ and $v$ are two arbitrarily chosen solutions.

I think I am able to prove the forward implication but not the backwards one. We see :
\begin{equation}
au \equiv av \equiv b ( \mod m) \Rightarrow m | (au - b) \text{ and } m|(av-b)
\end{equation}
Where $x|y$ means that $y$ is divisible by $x$. The above implies :
\begin{align}
& \Rightarrow m | \left[ (au - b) - (av - b) \right]   \\\\
& \Rightarrow m | \left[ (au - av) + (b - b ) \right]  \\\\
& \Rightarrow m | (au - av)                            \\\\
& \Rightarrow au \equiv av ( \mod m)
\end{align}
So this implies :
\begin{align}
\Rightarrow m | (au - av) \Rightarrow m | a(u-v)
\end{align}
We then see :
\begin{equation}
\text{gcd}(a,m) = 1 \text{ and } m | a(u-v) \Rightarrow m | (u-v) \text{ and } m \not | a
\end{equation}
Where $m \not | a$ means that $a$ is not divisible by $m$.

So in this case :
\begin{equation}
u \equiv v ( \mod m ) \; \checkmark
\end{equation}

So here I've shown that :
\begin{equation}
\text{gcd}(a,m) = 1 \text{ and } au \equiv av \equiv b (\mod m) \Rightarrow u \equiv v (\mod m)
\end{equation}
But I haven't shown that :
\begin{equation}
\text{gcd}(a,m) \neq 1 \text{ and } au \equiv av \equiv b (\mod m) \Rightarrow u \not \equiv v (\mod m)
\end{equation}
Can anyone help me with how to prove the converse ?

Comment: Hint: Bezout's identity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that if $b = dk$ where $gcd(m, a) = d$, there are $d$ solutions to $ax \equiv b \mod m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149684/prove-that-if-b-dk-where-gcdm-a-d-there-are-d-solutions-to-ax-eq) . Let $\gcd(a,m) = d$. If $d = 1$, the linked post shows there's a unique solution. Otherwise, with $d \gt 1$, then if $d \nmid b$, there are no solutions, else there are $d$ as shown in the linked post, with the number of solutions not being $1$, i.e., is not unique, in either case.

Comment: Formatting note:  using "\nmid" instead of "\not |" looks a lot better...$a\,\nmid \,b$ instead of $a\,\not |\, b$